# Troubles with google speech-to-text long recognition and punctuation

Tags: python, google-speech-api

I'm having troubles implementing speech-to-text long recognition especially with automatic punctuation.
I'm aware of it being still in beta. Short audio files are no problem, but when trying to transcript longer files (already in a storage bucket and accessed over the gcs_uri) it always ends up outputting the following error: "google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 minute use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter".

The enable_automatic_punctuation works with audiofiles shorter than 1 minute located in the storage bucket.

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types

gcs_uri = 'gs://bucket/audiofile.wav'
client = speech.SpeechClient.from_service_account_json('/service_account.json')

audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
language_code='de-DE',
enable_automatic_punctuation=True)

operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
response = operation.result(timeout=9000)

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print('-' * 20)
    print('First alternative of result {}'.format(i))
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

"google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 minute use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter" even though the audiofiles are already stored in the bucket and accessed from there